# Sound Pool in android

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I trying to make an app, with a lot of short sounds(more than 20), using Sound Pool.
But when i load that sounds, it take like 3-10 sec to load it.
How can i improve speed of loading?
Here is Function of loading

```
private int loadSound(String filename) {
    AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor;
    try {
        assetFileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(filename);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
   return soundPool.load(assetFileDescriptor,1);
}
```

Comment: If they are common sounds (perhaps a game that play them as events a lot.), then load them in memory and keep replaying the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use .OGG files at the lowest sample rate you can tolerate, like 96kb/s.  This will create the smallest files so they load faster.  I had a lot of problems with loading/playing sounds using .WAV files, they all went away when I converted them to .OGG files.
- Do your sound loading off the main UI thread.  If you need to know when the sound is loaded, use an `OnLoadCompleteListener`:

  ```
  mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
      @Override
      public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
          Log.d(TAG, "soundpool onLoadComplete, sampleId = " + sampleId + ", status = " + status);

          // ... sound is ready to play            
      }
  });

  // sound load should happen off the UI thread
  new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(getActivity(), R.raw.sound1, 1);
          // ... load other sounds here
      }
  }.start();
  ```

  I embedded the audio files so I could use raw resource ids.  If you have to load from files, grab all your filenames and send them off to a load method inside a non-UI thread.